# Set UIButton Frame at the center of UIImgeView

Tags: iphone, ios

Here is my code to set at the center

```
UIButton *videoImage = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake((secondImageView.frame.size.width/2)-50,(secondImageView.frame.size.height/2)-50,50,50)];
videoImage.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(ang*(3.14/180));
[videoImage setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"PlayButton.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[videoImage addTarget:self action:@selector(PlayMusicOnClickofButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[secondImageView addSubview:videoImage];
videoImage.tag  = k+1000;
secondImageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[videoImage release];
```

The problem that i am facing is when i change orientation of button it's position gets changed. It doesn't remain at center. Please help

Thanks

Comment: you need to use struts and springs. check out the autoresizingMask property for uiview class.

Comment: try using videoImage.center = secondImageView.center

Comment: i did that but did n't worked

Answer (score 3):

Actually you should use this method....

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation 
   {
         if(interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
         {
                    //handle how you want to show in landscape mode
         }
         else
         {
                    //handle how you want to show in portrait mode
         }
         return YES; 
   }
```

Comment: @dimplepanchal Issue is related to Rotation, not orientation

Answer (score 1):

You need to handle this. What you are doing is correct. You need to do tweak it when the orientation changes as the dimensions of your parent view change. Implement `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation` delegate. check this out -

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation 
                                         duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    if(toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft||toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
    {
        //handle how you want to show in landscape mode
    }
    else
    {
        //handle how you want to show in portrait mode
    }
}
```

Comment: my imageview is rotated at particular angle and now i have to add button in that view that too rotated at the same angle how can i do this i am not changing orientation of my device

Comment: @Srikar Issue is related to Rotation, not orientation